# YA book involving a planet with dragons and double-K in people's names

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I remember reading, in the 80s, an English-language teen-SF novel involving two teen protagonists (1 male, 1 female) on a planet (not Earth) that might have had some history of slavery (or inter-caste strife) and had dragons. Almost every character had a double KK in their name, though that might have been a caste marker.

That's literally all I remember, except that the author might have been female. (My head keeps suggesting Marion Zimmer Bradley, but I'm pretty sure it's not her.) If I read it in the 1980s, it was almost certainly written in the 1970s or 1980s.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9314/1234), with character names of: Jakkin, Sarkkhan, Akki, Errikin  etc

Comment: I did read that question before posting this (indeed it was reading that question that made me remember to ask this one) and it genuinely didn't seem familiar. As is probably obvious from me thinking it was _Pern_ until [Mark Beadles](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4024/mark-beadles) edited his answer. Memory is a curious thing.

Comment: You read quite a few by Julian May, It wasn't one of hers?

Comment: No, definitely the first of [The Pit Dragon Trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pit_Dragon_Trilogy). All the [Julian May](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_May) books I read were from [The Saga of Pliocene Exile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saga_of_Pliocene_Exile) and the related [Galactic Milieu series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Milieu_Series).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: Nope, not Pern. It's the [Pit Dragon Trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pit_Dragon_Trilogy) which has a lot of names with "kk". Otherwise the stories are generally similar.

---

There was a [character named Brekke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characters_in_Dragonriders_of_Pern) in the [Pern novels](http://concord.wikia.com/wiki/Pern_%28series%29) by Anne McCaffrey.

Comment: ...and also a Mikkala

Comment: That would be them. Thank you. Scanning through Wikipedia, I think it was [_Dragondrums_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragondrums) that I'm remembering. _*goes to Amazon*_

Comment: Oops! I edited at the same time!

Comment: And you're right, it's definitely [_The Pit Dragon Trilogy_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pit_Dragon_Trilogy). How curious that _Dragondrums_ seemed so familiar, when reading the Pit Dragon article it's really very obviously that. What a curious thing memory is. Though now I want to read Anne McCaffery's books too ;o)

Comment: @OwenBlacker careful, there are a lot of them ;)

Answer (score 1):

One of Anne McCaffrey's Pern books?