# What fantasy book has a character acquire powers by sleeping in a dead dragon's body?

Tags: story-identification, dragons

I read this novel a very long time ago, so the details are hazy, of course.  All I clearly remember is that the main character has to sleep in the body of a dead dragon (to escape inclement weather, maybe?) and ends up acquiring powers because of it.  I seem to remember that it was a girl, though that may be wrong, and I believe there was something about rainbows.  I also think, for some reason, that she was a slave, but again that could be wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What sort of powers?

Comment: Possible duplicates?
http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10240/1234
http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9314/1234

Comment: @Xantec I think the second one sounds a lot like what I remember.  I looked earlier, but didn't find anything; thanks for sharing that!

Comment: I remember a book like this where the characters vision changes, I don't think it's the Pit Dragon Trilogy, I'll have a search and see if I can find it.

Comment: I am also looking for this book and can't remember the title or author, I do believe the character was male, but I could be wrong on that. The character is sleeping in the dragon to avoid freezing, and the power is telepathic communication with dragons through images.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds like [The Pit Dragon Trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pit_Dragon_Trilogy). Your memories specifically sound like the end of the second book (although the synopsis on Wiki may not seem like it):

> Golden, Jakkin, and Akki flee to the mountains, but Golden is badly injured. Pursued by the Wardens, they are forced to leave Golden behind in a cave which they had sheltered in during Dark After, using Heart's Blood's body as a door and heater. Jakkin manumits the traitorous Erikkin, and Heart's Blood dies from a stinger shot in the neck, her body saving Jakkin and Akki. The only shelter they have during Dark After, is Heart's Blood's body, so they crawl into her birth sac. In the morning, Jakkin and Akki are reborn out of the dragon blood, and became the first real human Austarians, linked to each other and Heart's Blood's five hatchlings.

Comment: The Wiki doesn't sound at all correct, but I think that might be it.  I'm not 100% sure, but it sounds close enough.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, let us know after you get a chance to read the books.

Comment: Yea, your memories are vastly different then the other two questions (see comment on the main Q), but this is what I thought of after reading your question. The rainbows you remember I believe are how the main characters perceived the thoughts of the dragons (as color bursts in their mind). The main dragon of the first two books had a particularly colorful mind speech (rainbow-esque), likely due to its upbringing as well as being a mute. Most other dragons were dull and mono-chromatic in their thoughts.

Answer (score 6):

I'll give it a shot...

That sounds a bit like the scene in the Chronicles of Narnia book *Voyage of the Dawn Treader.* Eustace Scrubb sleeps next to a dead dragon in its cave and, after putting on a magical armlet, accidentally *becomes* a dragon.

I hope you find your answer!

Comment: Which character? Do they fit the OP's description?

Comment: Eustace Scrubb turns into a dragon after putting on a bracelet from the dragon's hoard. Doesn't sound like quite the same story.

Comment: I know it wasn't Narnia, I've read those fairly recently and what I'm remembering is very different.  Thanks, though!

Answer (score 2):

Try *[The Iron Dragon's Daughter](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25781.The_Iron_Dragon_s_Daughter)* by Michael Swanwick

[image: Book cover]

> A slave in a dragon factory that manufactures flying fighting machines, Jane changes her destiny when a voice from a dragon promising freedom and revenge prompts her to escape and challenge the foundations of the world.

And, from [one of the reviews](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/60184905?book_show_action=true):

> The basic premise of The Iron Dragon's Daughter is of a world alongside ours where human children have been stolen to work in the great foundries where dragons are made. Our protagonist, determined to know a different life from the one she is currently leading, makes plans to steal one of the dragons and flee - her plan works well in some ways but not in others, as she is forced to take refuge among the people who enslaved her kind.